# TrueOs повторная установка

Tags: virtualbox, freebsd

Устанавливаю виртуальную машину PCBSD Desktop 18, устанавливается, ошибок не выдает, все ок,НО после установки перезагружается и появляется не вот такое меню с дальнейшей настройкой [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а опять вот такое [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и опять по новой предлагает начать установку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема? 
То же самое было  и с freebsd. ((

Comment: Может забыли iso отмонтировать от виртуалки и система каждый раз грузится с установочного DVD

Comment: Да, забыл) Спасибо большое за оперативность)